# Validate user password according to regex bash

Tags: bash

I've been trying to write bash script, that validates user input with given rules: length > 8, at least one digit, and at least one of these: [@, #, $]

So regex for that is this:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%&*+-=]).{8,})
```

I've tried this, but with no result:

```
result=$(echo $1 | egrep "((?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%&*+-=]).{8,})")
echo $result
```

with `$1` being input parameter. Also, I'd like to wrap it in IF clause, but `echo` never outputs anything. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `grep -P` for Perl support instead of `egrep`. And also check your regex that don't seem to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
[[ ${#1} -ge 8 && $1 =~ [0-9] && $1 =~ [@#$] ]] && result="$1"
```

or with three grep:

```
result=$(grep -E '.{8}' <<< "$1" | grep '[0-9]' | grep '[@#$]')
```